# best overloaded method match for `RestSharp.Deserialize<RootObject>(RestSharp.IRestResponse)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, restsharp

So i am working this project on Xamarin forms, and get the error as in title on

```
var rootObject = deserial.Deserialize<RootObject>(gameJson);
```

I am supposed to return the list of games to my app.How can i remove the error?

```
public async Task<Game[]> GetGamesAsync(){

                var client = new RestClient("http://mystore/");
                var request = new RestRequest ("api/Games", Method.GET);
                request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

                var apiKey = session ["ApiKey"];
                var userId = session ["UserId"];

                try
                {
                    request.AddHeader ("authenticationkey",apiKey.ToString ());
                    request.AddHeader ("authenticationid",userId.ToString ());
                } 
                catch{}

                IRestResponse response = client.Execute (request);
                statusCodeCheck (response);

                var gameJson = response.Content;

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {

                    RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer ();
                    var rootObject = deserial.Deserialize<RootObject>(gameJson); 
                    return rootObject.games;
                }
                else if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden){
                    return null;
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are looking for this but I also using Restsharp in portable library and I'm deserializing datacontracts with Json.NET's `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`
method. I have not encountered any problem with it yet.

Also another possible solution is that the returned data is wrapped and the main object is not the `RootObject`.